# Using grep to remove exact numbers (R)

Tags: r

I'm trying to remove every value that is exactly the number "1", however in trying this, values that contain the number 1 (for example, 11 and 12) are also removed. I tried using the fixed and value arguments but neither seemed to work. Here's my code:

```
NumGenus2 <- NumGenus[ grep(1, NumGenus$Number.in.Genus, invert = TRUE), ]
```

If anyone knows the solution to this it'd be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: perhaps `NumGenus[NumGenus$Number.in.Genus != 1,]` or with quotation "1" depending on the class.

Comment: @missuse Very simple and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As mssuse demonstrated grep is a function used to find patterns, whereas you are wanting to find exact matches which is exactly what the logical operators are designed to do.  One of the beauties of R is that these are simple and make understanding the code after it is written simple.

https://www.statmethods.net/management/operators.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, you are trying to remove all rows from your data frame where Number.in.Genus=1

Another way:

```
library(dplyr)

NumGenus2 <- NumGenus %>%
filter(Number.in.Genus!=1)
```